# Having trouble with functions and loop logic

Tags: python-3.x, function, loops

Can someone break this function down for me? I understand the if statement that x > y (10>5), so now the function will subtract 5 from 10. I don't understand how the rest of it works.

```
def func(x,y):
  while True:
    if x>y:
        x -= y 
    else:
        z = x-1
        x=y
        y=z
    if x <= 3:
        return y

print (func(10,5))
```

Comment: If x is greater than y, subtract y from x. Otherwise, assign z to x-1, make x equal to y, and y equal to z. Then, if x is less than or equal to 3, return y (and break the loop). Otherwise, repeat.

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 why not post this as an answer

Comment: My suggestion as being a new coder myself is to replace the variables on your function on a piece of paper and do the math manually (assuming you understand how the operators work), this will help you see the results.

Comment: @cowbert sure...

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone break this function down for me?

If x is greater than y, subtract y from x. Otherwise, assign z to x-1, make x equal to y, and y equal to z. Then, if x is less than or equal to 3, return y (and break the loop). Otherwise, repeat